# Saving Enum name instead of value in couchbase

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am working on spring data couchbase application.In oracle its saving the enum with name but in couchbase its value. I want to save enum name in couchbase instead of its value. But i dont want to change this below existing code.
Is there any way to do that?
And the enum is not a direct field in document. Its a key value in map of other attribute

```
public enum Foo {
    Moon("Night"),
    Star("Night"),
    Sun("Day");

    private String value;
    Foo(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }

public class Universe{
Map<Foo, <List<List<Cone>>> bar;
}
```

Couchbase entity class is using

```
private List<Universe> universe;
```

Comment: Hi welcome you can get an enums name from enum.name()

Comment: Moon.name()  https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-enum-name-method

Comment: I cannot modify toString to return this.name()

Comment: Cross reference to same question on Couchbase Forum: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/saving-enum-by-name-in-couchbase/32206